# Can I detect when my service is killed by "Advanced Task Killer"

Tags: android, geolocation, task, kill, ondestroy

My app runs a geolocalisation service that the user can active or disactive by a toggleButton. To check the status of the service, I write a boolean in the Shared Preferences. I listen the beginning of the service and the end of it thanks to the onDestroy() of my service.

My problem is that: When the user kill the service with the "advanced task killer", I can't know that the service is killed, the onDestroy is not called !

How can I deal with that?

Thanks for your help.

Florent

Comment: I hope there's no way to do so. If I use Advanced Task Killer to kill a process, what I would expect is that the process won't be alive again (unless I explicitly execute it). It will be annoying to have an imortal process.

Comment: I just want to know if the service is alive or not. I know that Advanced Task killer will kill the process but I have no way to detect that the service is killed because the onDestroy is not called.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://www.vintage-computer.com/vcforum/archive/index.php/t-5628.html) can provide some inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a process is killed (using ATK or android's own force stop button, or the function [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29)), it is immediately purged from memory (if the kernel allows it).  This means there's no chance for any additional code to run, meaning there is no way to really deal with a "force kill" sent to your application.

If you want to handle this, you have 2 options (that I can think of):

1. Publish a disclaimer telling users to add your app to the "ignore" list of ATK.
2. Find some way to maintain functionality without relying on the onDestroy() method.

**EDIT:**

If you want to check for your process from a list of currently-running processes, look into [getRunningAppProcesses()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29).

Answer (score -2):

`onDestroy()`

If you want to restart the service, you can restart in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: onDestroy() is not usually called when app has been killed.

Comment: According to a majority of responses on SO: onDestroy() is not called when a service is killed by the system. Besides, if you'd like to have your service restarted automatically, you'd use START_STICKY in the first place.