# How to be warned that my service is being killed?

Tags: android, android-service

I have an app with a service with return `Service.START_STICKY` in his onStartCommand. This service log the user locations to send it every hours in batch to the server. To economize the battery life I don't store the log to the disk, i simply keep it in memory. problem :

1. when the user kill the application, then it's look like the service is also killed but the ondestroy of the service is not fired. So how can i know when the service is being to be close/destroyed to save to disk all the log to retrieve it later ?
2. when the system restart the service thank to START_STICKY it's seam the onStartCommand is not called. is it a normal behavior ?

Comment: refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862045/can-i-detect-when-my-service-is-killed-by-advanced-task-killer

Comment: I think that you are wasting battery exactly by storing data in memory. Why don't you just call a AlarmManager every hour to do whatever you want?

Comment: @VladMatvienko: it's exactly what i do, i call an alarm manager every hours to send to the server the collected locations (network use lot of baterry so this why i send locations in batch every hours). but i store these location in memory (and it's not use any noticeable memory)

Comment: so you are tracking the location all the time?

Comment: "i store these location in memory" -- do not do that. Heap space is **only a cache**, because your process can be terminated at any point in time without warning. Save the data to disk. "So how can i know when the service is being to be close/destroyed to save to disk all the log to retrieve it later ?" -- that is not possible, by definition. If you are not being called with `onDestroy()`, your process is simply being terminated.

Comment: @VladMatvienko: yes all the time

Comment: @CommonsWare : so how to efficiently save the lat/lng to the disk ? i mean it's look much more complicate, because if the process can be killed like this then maybe the file can be half written when the process is killed ?

Comment: @CommonsWare: so to resume i need to save to disk lat/long/accuracy/time but what the best way to do this ? i preferences maybe? later i send them to the server in json string

Comment: "because if the process can be killed like this then maybe the file can be half written when the process is killed" -- use SQLite, as it is transactional and so greatly reduces the likelihood of this occurrence (which is not all that likely to begin with).

Comment: is it not a little too much heavy to add sqlite just for this ?